# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В 2014 году, как при 5-дневной, так и при 6-дневной рабочей неделе(,) предпраздничными рабочими днями являются следующие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом предложении однородные члены соединены двойным составным союзом "как..., так и", который может быть заменен повторяющимся союзом "и...,и". В этом случае, согласно общеизвестному правилу, запятая не ставится после окончания ряда однородных членов, когда после них продолжается предложение. Поэтому единственно возможным является вариант: "В 2014 году как при 5-дневной, так и при 6-дневной рабочей неделе предпраздничными рабочими днями являются следующие".

Comment: Ну почему же, если это пояснение, то обособление возможно, это от автора зависит.

Comment: Авторские знаки, думаю, возможны тогда, когда они не противоречат устоявшимся твердым правилам

Comment: Пояснение и присоединение - всегда от автора, но в языке  есть.

Comment: Поэтому хорошо бы знать назначение текста. Если текст официальный, предпочтительнее вариант классический, который отстаивает Виктор. Да и в упражнении, когда ученик осваивает основные случаи постановки знаков, тоже. А если нужно передать авторскую интонацию, тогда, конечно, идем за автором текста.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна запятая. Это обособленный оборот, состоящий из двух обстоятельств, связанных союзом КАК...ТАК И.

ОТВЕТ 2. Я рассматривала необособленный вариант, но он  мне не понравился. Во-первых, оборот такого вида в составе основного сообщения  выглядит  громоздко и «не читается». Во-вторых, он содержит дополнительную информацию, которую желательно отнести на второй план речи. Можно еще предложить обособление скобками: «В 2014 году (как при 5-дневной, так и при 6-дневной рабочей неделе) предпраздничными рабочими днями являются следующие…».

ОТВЕТ 3. Предлагаю оценить правильность построения предложения и подумать над следующими вопросами: А) Как вы выразите перечислительную интонацию однородных членов в таком предложении? Б) Однородные члены, связанные двойным союзом КАК...ТАК И, обычно не встречаются в середине предложения, а чаще встречаются в конце предложения. Если это действительно так, то почему?

ОТВЕТ 4. Хочу немного уточнить свою позицию по поводу структуры и интонации предложения. Однородные члены, связанные двойным союзом, обычно стоят в конце предложения, Например: Пушкину принадлежит много произведений как в стихах, так и в прозе. Законы издаются как на федеральном, так и региональном уровнях. Озеро является прекрасным местом для отдыха как зимой, так и летом.

Такая позиция не случайна, так как  структура и интонация этих предложений должна ВЫРАЗИТЬ сочинительную связь однородных членов, что соответствует  перечислительной интонации. Это выглядит, к примеру,  так: Пушкину принадлежит много произведений как в стихах (ПОВЫШЕНИЕ ТОНА, ПАУЗА), так и в прозе (ПОНИЖЕНИЕ ТОНА). Однородные члены имеют тоническое ударение, и мы чувствуем это в устной речи.

А  можно ли выразить сочинительную связь однородных членов, находящихся в середине предложения? Боюсь, что нет, и тогда предложение без обособления не просто плохо  читается, а вообще является неправильным. И в то же время обособление запятыми выглядит несимпатично – непонятно, к чему эти запятые относятся. Остаются или скобки, или надо предложение перестраивать.

Comment: Если бы такие вещи решались голосованием, я бы проголосовал за скобки. В конце концов, выбор знаков препинания в русском языке не прибит гвоздями... Текст - официальный, так что скобки смотрятся нормально. Вот в художественном...

Answer (score 0):

Если после "В 2014 году" запятая стоит, значит,это пояснительный оборот, обосабливается с двух сторон. Если б не было первой запятой, можно было бы не ставить и вторую, это обособление факультативно.

В 2014 году, как при 5-дневной, так и при 6-дневной рабочей неделе, предпраздничными рабочими днями являются следующие.

В 2014 году как при 5-дневной, так и при 6-дневной рабочей неделе предпраздничными рабочими днями являются следующие.

Comment: Последний вариант, приведенный Вами, Людмила, я считаю единственно правильным